# Determining Min - Max within zip code (statistics by area)?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, statistics

I'm new to ArcGIS Desktop. I have created a layer representing zip codes and overlayed it with a layer containing some data points. I want to find the min and max value of the data points in each zip code. Currently, I am manually checking the values if all the data points in each zip code but this is becoming very time-consuming and cumbersome.

Is there a faster way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do an INTERSECT of the data points with the Zip Code polygon layer - then with your result - do a SUMMARY STATISTICS with the Data point as your Statistics Field - Min and/or Max statistic type and your Zip Code as your Case Field.

Answer (score 0):

Yes!

Do a [Select by Location](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00s50000002q000000) -- selecting from = data points layer, source layer = zip codes layer, spatial relationship "within source layer."

Open the attribute table for the data points layer, [right-click on the attribute column you're interested in and select Statistics](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/Viewing_statistics_for_a_table/005s00000057000000/). In the window that comes up, you'll see the min and max values (as well as other basic stats).

Comment: Hi! I tried to do the Select by Location, but my data points layer didn't show up in the Target Layer/selecting from layer.

Comment: @V_N Is your data points layers added to the map document you are working in?

Comment: Yes, it's been added and color coded according to the range of values. It was a file with 3 columns: the latitude, longitude and a value/attribute. I plotted it using the Display XY coordinates option.

Comment: @V_N I think you need to convert it to shapefile for it to display in the Select By Location tool.  You can do this by right-clicking your layer and going to Data, then Export Data.

Comment: I tried to save it as a shape file, but it said output name not valid. The name of my layer currently is 'Sheet11$ Events'.

Comment: @V_N You can choose your own name, like Points or any descriptive name.  The error is because you can't use characters like $ in your name.  When you name your shapefile only use letters, numbers and underscores.  Avoid spaces in the name or starting it with a number.

Comment: One more note - when you follow Erica's answer, make sure you select the zip code you are interested in before doing the "Select by Location" tool, so it only selects the points in that zip code.  If I read her answer right, you'll need to do the zip codes one by one.  Someone may be able to come up with an automated solution for you if you really have a lot to do.

Comment: I changed the name of my layer to Sheet1Events. But i'm getting the same error. This is the screenshot of what I'm getting https://fbcdn-sphotos-d-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-xap1/t1.0-9/10336815_10154213820010241_2853985668295330421_n.jpg

Comment: @V_N I don't see an error message in the screenshot, but maybe reading the ESRI help will help you sort it out. http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//00s50000000t000000

Comment: @Sara Barnes I managed to create the shapefile and do the select by location, but like you said, all zip codes got selected, how do you suggest I select a particular zip code?

Comment: @V_N You can use the "Select Features" tool to click on the zip code area you want, or you can open the attribute table and choose that line.  Either way, your selected zip code will show in a blue highlight.  Then when you run the "Select by Location" tool, check the "Use selected features" option under Source Layer.

Comment: @V_N While this solution does simplify the calculation portion of the problem by displaying the min/max of a group of selected points, it still relies on selecting and checking each zip code individually. The other answer is a faster solution where by combining your two datasets into one you can get all the desired values in a single table with a single command.